# Show non regularity of a language using closure property

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

Show that the language $\{0^n1^m0^n| m,n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not regular using closure properties.

I tried showing this using pumping lemma but I am stuck when it comes to closure properties. Please help me out!

Comment: It is a bit difficult to answer if we don't know what non-regular languages you know of. For example, you could show that $L \cap 0^*10^* = \{0^n10^n\mid n\geqslant 0\}$ is non-regular and use closure properties of regular languages.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1031/755, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties